# About the linx dts(device tree) include files?

Tags: dts

I come across a problem as follows:

there is a origin dts or dtsi files in the linux kernel dir:

```
 arch/arm64/boot/dts/
```

Assume that there is a file : B.dtsi

I want to create a A file in that direction:

now arch/arm64/boot/dts/A/

i want to create dts file C.dts in A dir,then it include the file coming from dts/xx.dtsi

i can use the absolute dir path in  file C.dts

```
include "arch/arm64/boot/dts/B.dtsi"
```

But is there a -i option like C compile ,the dtc tool can search the include file automatic after i set the compile option?

Answer (score 1):

There is -i option when compiling dtb

use:

```
DTC_FLAGS ?= -i $(DCT_EXTRA_PATH)
```

then you should use:

```
#include <B.dtsi>
```

or

```
/include/ "B.dtsi"
```

in your dtsi files

Comment: Hi! what is the actual command you used? Did you use make command?